# Disable setting cursor in the middle of a link in a text view

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uitextview

I'd like to disable editing links in a text view, that's why I need to disable setting cursor in the middle of the link. The video link demonstrates what I want to accomplish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOOC9A93kn8

Any ideas how to achieve that are much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the cursor in a `UITextField` like this:

```
if let selectedTextRange = textField.selectedTextRange {
    let cursorPosition = textField.offset(from: textField.beginningOfDocument,
                                          to: selectedTextRange.start)
}
```

You can offset the cursor by doing something like this:

```
let offset = 2
if let positionWithOffset = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument,
                                               offset: offset) {
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: positionWithOffset,
                                                      to: positionWithOffset)
}
```

So you can use that in `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` from `UITextFieldDelegate` to achieve the behavior you want by offsetting the cursor to the beginning of the link.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try